# how to avoid blank page at the end of pdf report in BIRT?

Tags: java, birt

I am using current BIRT version that is 4.5. I have two master pages in my report. I have huge data to display on a report so i have set some data to display on one master page and the remaining on another master page due to some reason. The problem is when there is no data to display on one of the master page it is rendering a blank page with header and footer of that master page which i want to avoid. In my pdf report how can i avoid this blank page?

Hi, all are pointing to hide tables or other components but my requirement here is, i need to hide the page itself. I dont think there is visibility option for page. even if it is there it is not so useful. Kindly understand that i dont want to display the page itself not only the components in it.so can i expect any help now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When no data returned BIRT displays blank page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24136707/when-no-data-returned-birt-displays-blank-page)

Comment: I dont want to display a statement. I dont want to display the page at all.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you added the tables directly on the masterpage?

That's not how it works. BIRT will render the (master)page and maybe hide the elements on them (for example a table that has no data. You can do this by setting the visibility property). The problem with this approach is that the Masterpage cannot be 'unrenderred'.

The proper way to fix this, is to add each element on the normal layout. In the properties for each table, grid, etc. you can set the pagebreak properties. Here you can select the Masterpage you want to use. If an element does not need to be rendered (by visibility settings), it wont trigger a 'blank' masterpage.

Hope that helps.